# Gson/Volley Android get messages rather than data from response

Tags: java, android, realm, android-volley, gson

I am doing a request to an api endpoint that when it fails will provide the information in the messages part of the response as seen here:

```
{
    "data":[],
    "messages":{
        "payment_required":{
            "amount":"265.00"
            }
        },
    "code":"",
    "status":"failed",
    "status_code":400
}
```

On the android app I am handing the `JsonObjectRequest` as seen here:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, data,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                changeColourInterface.requestSuccess();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;

        if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {

            String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);

            Log.v("ChangeColour", jsonError);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                    .create();

            ChangeModelVersionResponse changeModelVersionResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonError, ChangeModelVersionResponse.class);

            realm.beginTransaction();

            realm.copyToRealm(changeModelVersionResponse.data);

            realm.commitTransaction();

            changeColourInterface.requestFailed(changeModelVersionResponse.data);
        }
    }
});

queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
```

I get into the `onErrorResponse` section, but when I try to create a local realm db row in the ChangeModelVersion table I get an error. This is because the `GSON` response is looking for the "data" section. But I need it to look for the messages section.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is where the `data` value is being accessed:

```java
realm.copyToRealm(changeModelVersionResponse.data);
```

If your `ChangeModelVersionResponse` type already includes a `messages` field, you can update this to something like (exact syntax may differ slightly, depending on Realm APIs):

```java
realm.copyToRealm(changeModelVersionResponse.messages);
```

If your `ChangeModelVersionResponse` type does not already include a `messages` field, you'll need to add that field (and create any classes it depends on) before you can update the line above.

Comment: As you answered I realised exactly that, stupid mistake. Thanks anyway!